# Linq 2 SQL and custom extension method

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, extension-methods

I'm stuck on a stupid step when building my application.

I have a simple query on linq 2 sql:

```
var recipients = cdc.Recipients.Where(r => r.Owner == Sanitize.SanitizeUserName(context.User.Identity.Name) && r.Enabled == true && (r.DisplayName.Contains(qs) || r.EmailAddress.Contains(qs)))
                                        .Select(r => new NVC { name = r.DisplayName, value = r.EmailAddress }).ToList();
```

which take to the recipient's table some data and put on a custom class. All smooth here.

I need to add an extra filter on the where clause to check if the email address is valid.

I tried with a simple function but it threw a "no sql translation" exception when used it.

Digging thru the interwebs I found that I must use extensions method so I eventually build this:

```
public static Expression<Func<string, bool>> IsSaneEmail = y => (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(y) && Regex.IsMatch(y, emailPattern));
```

(where emailPattern is a regex string)

But how to apply to my query? I tried to add on the where clause

```
... && IsSaneEmail(r.emailAddress) && ...
```

or

```
... && r.EmailAddress.IsSaneEmail() && ...
```

with no luck.

I know I'm that dumb, but help me

Answer (score 1):

You cant do that in Linq2SQL (cant be translated into SQL) you must first convert to IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

Your extension method needs to target the string class and it should be returning bool:

```
public static bool IsSaneEmail(this string val) {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(val) && Regex.IsMatch(val, emailPattern)
    }
```

Once that is sorted you will be able to call this method as such:

```
r.EmailAddress.IsSaneEmail()
```

Comment: Nope, still the same "no sql translation" exception.

Comment: In that case I guess you need to retrieve the whole collection to memory using e.g. ToList() and filter it afterwards...

Comment: Yeah that's an idea but what about large collections? It would be inefficent